# Directus Error: Error while obtaining machine id: Error: spawn cmd.exe ENOENT

Tags: mysql, content-management-system, directus

So after i run  `npm run dev -w directus` i get this message

```
10:54:48 ÔÜá´©Å  Upload directory (C:\xampp\htdocs\directus\api\uploads) is not read/writeable!
10:54:48 ÔÜá´©Å  Extensions directory (C:\xampp\htdocs\directus\api\extensions) is not readable!
10:54:48 Ô£¿ Server started at http://localhost:8055
Error: Error while obtaining machine id: Error: spawn cmd.exe ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:282:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:477:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\directus\node_modules\node-machine-id\dist\index.js:1:7964
    at exithandler (node:child_process:404:5)
    at ChildProcess.errorhandler (node:child_process:416:5)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:288:12)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:477:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
[ERROR] 10:54:48 Error: Error while obtaining machine id: Error: spawn cmd.exe ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:282:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:477:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

i dont know why im struggling so hard with this CMS. When i try to connect to the server there is just a failed connection.

Comment: the error says C:\xampp\htdocs\directus\api\uploads is not read wirte so change the attributes of that folder

Comment: Ok but now i have the problem that this folder does not exist at all in this directory...

Comment: a tool like pspad has a function to search directories and subfolders search for the term api\uploads and change the directory or you add a directory with that name at that position